# Problems capturing HTTP response

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I have this code which successfully makes an HTTP request:

```
                //Successful request
                var requestInBytes = encoding.GetBytes(urlWithParameters.ToString());

                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlWithParameters.ToString());
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentLength = requestInBytes.Length;
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();

                // Send the data.
                newStream.Write(requestInBytes, 0, requestInBytes.Length);
                newStream.Close();
```

However, I'm having trouble capturing the response. Right now, I'm trying this:

```
            //No response?
            System.IO.StreamReader st = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream());
            var response = st.ReadLine();
```

But this is coming back with a blank response?

Comment: You are only reading the first line of the response ... which appears to be blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
HTTPWebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

You can then check the various properties of the response.

OR

Try:

```
var response= req.ReadToEnd();
```